# JS: Dynamically create subproperties of non-existing property

Tags: javascript

I want something like this:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj["a"]["b"].push({"c":"d"});
```

I want myObj to become: `{"a":{"b":[{"c":"d"}]}}` but I get an error

> Cannot set property 'b' of undefined

Yes, I know I can create it step by step like that:

```
var myObj={};
myObj["a"]={};
myObj["a"]["b"]=[];
myObj["a"]["b"].push({"c":"d"});
```

But what if myObj already has some structure and I don't want to destroy it. E.g:

```
var myObj={"a":{"e":"f"}};
```

if I write `myObj["a"]={};` I'll lose data.
Sure I can write

```
if(myObj["a"]==null){
myObj["a"]={}
}
```

But it's too bulky! That would be great if I could just write smth like `myObj["a"]["b"].push({"c":"d"});` without checking for null on every step.
Any suggestions how to do this? May be there is a way to override JS native Object or smth like that?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could simplify the check -> `myObj["a"] = myObj["a"] || {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible to override JS's native functionalities like that.

You're going to have to check for sub-properties.

If you want to make sure a property exists on a object, without overriding it, do something like this:

```
myObj['a'] = myObj['a'] || {};
```

This sets `myObj['a']` to itself if it has a value, or to a new empty object if it doesn't.

Then do the same for `myObj['a']['b']`, and push to that:

```
myObj['a']['b'] = myObj['a']['b'] || [];
myObj['a']['b'].push({"c":"d"});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Netscape apologizes for the code bulk. Why not this?

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.a = {b:[{c:'d'}]};
```

Comment: `myObj.a = {b:[{c:'d'}]};`  
If I already have myObj structure, I don't want to lose it. E.g:  
`myObj={"a":{"e":"f"}}`

Comment: You likely need to reevaluate your object structure approach then. This technique you're seeking will not work for you.